# LINQ GroupBy 3 properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got the following class:

```
public class ProductInventory : Entity
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
}
```

and a class used in my ViewModels that looks like so:

```
 public class ProductInventoryCountModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get an output of `Dictionary<Manager, List<ProductInventoryCountModel>` that basically displays Products by manager and then by expiration date so that I can print out actual data looking something like this:

```
ManagerBoB

 --ProductA, Expires 8/15/13, Count: 10
 --ProductA, Expires 10/10/13, Count: 40
 --ProductB, Expires 6/13/13, Count: 30

ManagerTim

 --ProductA, Expires 10/10/13, Count: 5
 --ProductB, Expires 5/25/13, Count: 10
 --ProductB, Expires 6/13/13, Count 40
```

how would I write this query in LINQ when starting with a list of `ProductInventory`? I tried using multiple `.GroupBy` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that you want a `Dictionary<Manager, List<ProductInventoryCountModel>>`, so I think you'd have to do something like this:

```
var dictionary = 
    db.ProductInventory.GroupBy(x => new { x.Manager, x.Product, x.ExpirationDate })
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Manager,
                    g => g.Select(x => new ProductInventoryCountModel 
                                  {
                                      Product = x.Key.Product,
                                      ExpirationDate = x.Key.ExpirationDate,
                                      Count = x.Count()
                                  }).ToList());
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to group by an object with multiple properties:

```
list.GroupBy(p => new { p.Manager, p.Product.Name, p.ExpirationDate.Date })
```

This works because anonymous types implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to compare by value.